# Standard location of system-wide configuration files of an app?

Tags: windows-vista, registry-virtualization

Since Windows Vista, our friends from Redmond are putting an end to the habit of storing configuration files in `C:\Program Files\<AppName>\config.ini`.  Ok, they introduced [Registry Virtualisation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884(v=vs.85).aspx), but it's always better to fix your stuff, right?

I'm planning to fix a pre-Vista app which runs as a service, and which needs to maintain a machine-wide configuration file.

Where do I store the config file? And what would be the most portable/future-proof way of obtaining the path to that location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After improving my Google-fu starting from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269893/best-place-to-store-configuration-files-and-log-files-on-windows-for-my-program), I think I've found the definitive answer [in this microsoft blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2010/03/18/where-should-i-store-my-data-and-configuration-files-if-i-target-multiple-os-versions/) which actually describes much more than what I originally wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the values in the registry in something inheriting from `\HKLM\` directly, which would give portability.

If there are a large number of values, or a complex structure to them, then you could store a file location in the registry, and store your configuration at that destination.